# Need Help to optimize the following java code. It is the code for setting color of specific keywords in a textview.(Android Application)

Tags: java, android, performance, html, spannable

I'm  developing an app to view C-programs.I wanted to give a simple color scheme to the text which is stored in database,retrieved as string and then passed on to the textview.

The code I have written assigns green color to header file declarations and brackets,blue color is assigned to numbers,printf,scanf...red is assigned to datatypes such as int,char,float.

It is however very inefficient.Before applying this color scheme,my app was displaying the textview activity instantly.Now,depending on the length of the programs it takes up to 4 to 5 seconds which is really poor performance.

what it does is,it takes one keyword at a time,then iterates the complete text of textview looking for that particular keyword only and changes its color,sets the text again.
Thus,it traverses text of the entire textview 29 times as I have defined 29 keywords in String arrays( namely keywordsgreen,keywordsblue,keywordsred).

**The activity's onCreate function contains the following code :**

```
        textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(programtext);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE6E6E6);

        //The problem stars here

        String [] keywordsgreen={"#define","#include","stdio.h","conio.h","stdlib.h","math.h","graphics.h","string.h","malloc.h","time.h","{","}","(",")","<",">","&","while ","for "};
        for(String y:keywordsgreen)
        {
        fontcolor(y,0xff21610B);
        }

        String [] keywordsred={"%d","%f","%c","%s","int ","char ","float","typedef","struct ","void "};
        for(String y:keywordsred)
        {
        fontcolor(y,0xFFB40404);
        }

        String [] keywordsblue={"printf","scanf","\n","getch","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
        for(String y:keywordsblue)
        {
        fontcolor(y,0xFF00056f);
        }
```

**The fontcolor function is as follows :**

```
private void fontcolor(String text,int color) 
    {
        Spannable raw=new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);
        while (index >= 0) 
        {
          raw.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), index, index + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
        }
        textView.setText(raw);
    }
```

Comment: Probably better to post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This project, [android-codepad](https://code.google.com/p/android-codepad/) comes with source so you can see how they do it. Alternatively, [ShaderEditor](https://github.com/markusfisch/ShaderEditor) also has source code for it.

Comment: By the way, moving the `getText`/`setText` outside the loops might be one simple but drastic performance improvement.